# Android Emulator Issue. GPU Issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I downloaded the new Android Studio 3.0 and its giving me a headache. When I start my emulator I get this GPU Driver issue pop and then after I click ok for it to go away. I ralize my log cat is filled with this code bellow the whole time. What is going on here?

```
    11-16 12:29:20.348 3351-3351/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-16 12:29:20.348 3351-3351/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-16 12:29:21.416 3351-3351/com.example.enoch.streamapptest W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.enoch.streamapptest-2/lib/x86
11-16 12:29:21.534 3351-3351/com.example.enoch.streamapptest I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-16 12:29:21.827 3351-3351/com.example.enoch.streamapptest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-16 12:29:23.135 3351-3383/com.example.enoch.streamapptest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-16 12:29:23.135 3351-3383/com.example.enoch.streamapptest D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-16 12:29:23.157 3351-3383/com.example.enoch.streamapptest D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9d563380: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-16 12:29:23.223 3351-3383/com.example.enoch.streamapptest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d563380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d552710)
11-16 12:29:23.311 3351-3351/com.example.enoch.streamapptest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
11-16 12:29:23.325 3351-3383/com.example.enoch.streamapptest D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d563380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d552710)
```

Comment: this does not theme like a problem. Do you have any problems with the emulator?

Comment: no but now I cannot view any logs. Which is a problem

Comment: `com.example.enoch.streamapptest` <- is this yourapp's package ?

Comment: yes thats my package

Comment: I can suggest you some options, that are not fixes, but workarounds: 1) You can filter logcat messages with filter string, using RegExp. I have similar problem with Samsung devices spamming my LogCat with some Bluetooth trash. basically, Regext I use is: `^(?!.*(String to remove)).*$`. To remove multiple strings, you can find a suitable regexp in few minutes over the internet. 2) Use different non-default Android Emulator. I'd suggest Genymotion.